# Downloading data daily with Python

Tags: python, schedule

Hi I created a function to download data from a crypto exchange and I would like to automate this process so that I don't need to do it myself. I looked at schedule but it throws me an error. here is the code:

```
symbols = ['BTCUSDT', 'ETHUSDT', 'ADAUSDT', 'BNBUSDT', 'DOTUSDT', 'XRPUSDT', 'UNIUSDT', 'LTCUSDT', 'LINKUSDT',
       'BCHUSDT', 'XLMUSDT', 'LUNAUSDT', 'DOGEUSDT', 'VETUSDT','ATOMUSDT', 'AAVEUSDT', 'FILUSDT', 'AVAXUSDT',
       'TRXUSDT', 'EOSUSDT', 'SOLUSDT', 'IOTAUSDT', 'XTZUSDT', 'NEOUSDT', 'CHZUSDT', 'DAIUSDT', 'SNXUSDT',
       'SUSHIUSDT', 'EGLDUSDT', 'ENJUSDT', 'ZILUSDT', 'MATICUSDT', 'MKRUSDT', 'COMPUSDT', 'BATUSDT', 'ZRXUSDT',
       'RSRUSDT']

for symbol in symbols:
   schedule.every().day.at("21:00").do(get_all_binance(timeframe_folder = '1h',symbol, kline_size = '1h', save = True))
   schedule.every().day.at("21:00").do(get_all_binance(timeframe_folder = '30m',symbol, kline_size = '30m', save = True))
   schedule.every().day.at("21:00").do(get_all_binance(timeframe_folder = '4h',symbol, kline_size = '4h', save = True))
   schedule.every().day.at("21:00").do(get_all_binance(timeframe_folder = '12h',symbol, kline_size = '12h', save = True))
   schedule.every().day.at("21:00").do(get_all_binance(timeframe_folder = '1d',symbol, kline_size = '1d', save = True))

while True:
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(5)
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/louis/Desktop/Python_projects/streamlit_apps/dashboards/collect_data.py", line 70, in <module>
schedule.every().day.at("21:05").do(get_all_binance('1h',symbol, '1h', save = True))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 625, in do
self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

How can I fix this ? and are there any other solutions ? Thank you !

Comment: You can try scheduling like so:
  `schedule.every().day.at("21:00").do(get_all_binance, timeframe_folder = '1h',symbol, kline_size = '1h', save = True)`

Answer (score 0):

The first argument should be callable, meaning it should be the actual function object and not the return value of the function. What you are doing is this:

```
schedule.every().day.at("21:00").do(some_random_func())
```

What you should actually be doing is this:

```
schedule.every().day.at("21:00").do(some_random_func)
```

Notice how there are no brackets in the second one. This is because I am passing the actual function object as an argument. By having the brackets present, Python will call the function, and have the return value of the function passed as an argument instead, and because the return value of your function probably isn't a function, it throws the error stating that the value passed as the first argument was not a function as it expected.

The function you are passing (get_all_binance) has arguments, however, so you can either use lambdas or pass the arguments after the function:

Either this:

```
schedule.every().day.at("21:00").do(get_all_binance, ...args)
```

or this:

```
schedule.every().day.at("21:00").do(lambda: get_all_binance(...args))
```

A lambda is just an anonymous function, so "lambda: get_all_binance(...args)" returns a function that does the actions and returns the value get_all_binance. So all in all each line will look like this:

```
schedule.every().day.at("21:00").do(lambda: get_all_binance(timeframe_folder = '1h',symbol, kline_size = '1h', save = True))
```

Comment: Thank you for this clear explanation, I will remember it !